Make all faces in an object have the same texture tiling?
I am learning to make objects for Unity. I made the object in the picture. How can I make all faces have  the same texture tiling?

Also I have this set of faces that for some reason look odd (not have a texture tiling):

Even better: How would I make it so that in Unity, I have material slots that would assign themselves? For example if I have a bottle; material 1 for the bottle and material 2 for the wraper.
Thank you!

You must make seams, UV unwrap this object, and adjust the UV islands.

@DanielMöller What are seams? I just did UV unwrap and it seems to have worked. What are UV islands?

UV Unwrap
For the Texture to be displayed correctly, you have to UV unwrap your model.
Edit Mode -> Select all faces or only the portion that you want to unwrap -> (Top Menu) UV -> Select the method you want to use.
Seams
Seams are "cuts" along your mesh that help the UV with unwrap. You can select edges of your Model that should act as a cut in the UV. If you do not set any seams, blender will do it's best to create them itself.
In this picture you can see how a cube could be unwrapped. The seams are placed at the edges that are cut and no longer connected

Islands
Islands are disconnected UV parts of the same Model like you can see in this picture. If you are in edit mode and have face select enabled (not edge and not single vertices) you can hover over a created uv island and press "L". This will select all the faces of the island.

Procedural Textures
For Procedural Textures that have to flow over separate Objects you can create an empty, Us the "Object" Mapping method in the Shading node "Texture coordinate" and than select the Empty as an Object in this Node. This will take the Empty as a scale point which should give you equally sized Textures on all Objects.
Sadly I can not answer your question about Unity.

That with Unity might very well be. Your remark about the texturing is only half right. The scale will be the same but the orientation will not be. You can apply the rotation to fix this but you might not want to do this in certain situations.
